# searching words in Greek in Unix and Perl

Tags: perl, unix, special-characters

I have txt files that are greek and now I want to search specific words in them using perl and bash ... the words are like ?a?, t?, e??

I was searching for words in english and now want to replace them by greek but all I get is ??? mostly... for Perl:

```
my %word = map { $_ => 1 } qw/name date birth/;
```

and for bash

```
for X in name date birth
do
```

can someone please help me?

Comment: You should give us some more information about your problem. What is the encoding of your text file and what is the encoding of your locale settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# Tell Perl your code is encoded using UTF-8.
use utf8;

# Tell Perl input and output is encoded using UTF-8.
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';

my @words = qw( καί τό εἰς );

my %words = map { $_ => 1 } @words;
my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, keys %words;

while (<>) {
   if (/$pat/) {
      print;
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
script.pl file.in >file.out
```

Notes:

- Make sure the source code is encoded using UTF-8 and that you use `use utf8;`.
- Make sure you use the `use open` line and specify the appropriate encoding for your data file. (If it's not UTF-8, change it.)

Comment: Are you sure his file is utf-8 encoded? My guess is it is rather ISO 8859-1 or something alike and thus the whole trouble.

Comment: @mikyra, I told him what he needs. Any deviations could be trouble. There are 4 ways he could have deviated. Speculating which combination of those he got wrong is useless.

Comment: sorry new on coding so have no idea my used notepad++ to write it

Comment: @ikegami: when i want to put it inside the file I get the following 'qw/?a?, t?, e??/;'

Comment: You mean that's what appears in your editor when you paste the text into your editor? Sorry, I don't use Notepad++, so I can't help you with problems with your editor.

Comment: managed to change the encoding to UTF-* but i do still get a small erro... the middle letter of the last work comes as square

Comment: Probably just a font issue. (Right character, just can't get displayed by your editor's font.) If so, it'll still work.

Comment: Convert what? Nothing I said is OS-specific. You'll want to convert line endings of text files as always (say, by using `dos2unix`), but the program will work on all types of systems.

Comment: my perl is reading the outputs of another bash script which is not saying my files as UTF-8... I am wondering whether I can call anything to convert them or save them as UTF-8

Comment: I think you mean "... which isn't encoded using UTF-8" when you said "... which is not saying my files as UTF-8". That's not a problem. Just change the `use open` line to specify the encoding actually used.

Comment: I have included my full code...and the error I get running on linux terminal

Comment: That error is not from Perl. This is a brand new question for which you've given no usable information.

Comment: I will try to see where the problem is and find the write question to ask for it ...Thanks for the help